# Apache: Tomcat "any version" .exe or .zip

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat6

I have little bit confusion regarding apache tomcat installation.

So, I would like to know that whats the difference between the .zip and the .exe tomcat ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exe will install Tomcat as a Windows Service. The zip file will allow you to start and stop Tomcat using batch files or to manually install the service. If you want to integrate Tomcat with an IDE, you need the zip file, since the required batch files aren't included in the exe version.

Comment: +1, also have a look at `Packaging Details`: http://mirror.deri.at/apache/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.26/README.html

Comment: @kgiannakakis Tomcat can be integrated with Eclipse IDE by the exe installation as well!

Comment: @Narayan That is because Eclipse provides its own batch files. The important thing to note is that the batch files aren't included in the exe installer and if you needed them for whatever reason, you need to download the zip version. Actually you can download both and extract the zip file over the folder the exe installer has created. The contents of both are the same.